# Too many Ajax calls on expand all functionality on Kendo Grids with subgrids

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with a Kendo Grid that can have many rows (sometimes up to 500 rows), each with a subgrid with more data. A similar example can be found here (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html). I have added the ability to expand all of the subgrids. Essentially just a button that triggers a click event (via jQuery) on each of the dropdown arrows to expose the subgrids.

My issue here is the jQuery is essentially clicking on each of these dropdown arrows individually. This is a problem because when each arrow is clicked, it fires off an Ajax call. In this instance where I have 500 rows, that turns out to be 500 individual Ajax calls, which creates a large amount of loading/lag and sometimes renders my browser unresponsive.

Is there a better way to expand all rows/load data, as to not bog down the backend/frontend with lots of Ajax calls? Possibly a more efficient way of opening all the dropdowns and making one Ajax call for all the subgrid data? I am using the ASP.NET Kendo library to instantiate the grids.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement local data-binding(Kind of hybrid implementation) for the grid with nested(hierarchical) models for subgrids which incurs initial loading/lag and no further overhead. Assuming you are using C# wrappers:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<AssetViewModel> Assets { get; set; }
}

public class AssetViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AssetName { get; set; }        
}
```

And view will be:

```
@model IEnumerable<IRAS.Animation.Pipeline.ViewModel.ProjectManagement.TestViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);       
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(430)) 
    .Filterable()
    .DetailTemplate(@<text>
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid(item.Assets)
            .Name("grid_"+item.Id)
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.Id);
                columns.Bound(o => o.AssetName);                
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(5)
                .ServerOperation(false)
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()            
    )
                </text>)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Server()
        .PageSize(20)               
     )
)
```

and definitely we need to provide hierarchical model collection from controler-action to view. We are making use of .Ajax() and .Server() simultaneously, so master grid will server bind things (sorting, grouping, filtering). Now we can expand all of the subgrids with on button click without single call to server.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the grid according to the example, then you have a detailInit function to load the detail. You said that your button calls the expandRow method for each row. 
To avoid the multiple AJAX calls I would try the following:

- when the button I clicked to open all details, load all the details into an javascript object
- write a second detailInit function to use to use the javascript object instead of an AJAX call to load the detail data
- then exchange the original detailInit function with the second detailInit function
- then call expandRow method for each row
- then exchange the second detailInit function with the orginal detailInit function to restore normal behavior

UPDATE:

I missed the part:

> I am using the ASP.NET Kendo library to instantiate the grids.

So my solution might be not applicable for Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC server wrappers.